# Is there a smarter way to declare my 15 ints

Tags: c

Got a quick question, I'm fairly new so please mind my ignorance.

Is there a smarter way to declare these 15 `int`s, without the use of an array?

```
int r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15 = 0;
```

Comment: If you cannot use an array, or some type of data structure, then no, that's the only way. I have no idea why someone would want you to do that. You should also individually set them equal to 0 if that is what you want, because just setting the last one equal to zero won't set r1-14 to 0.

Comment: using an array has another advantage: you can address the element with the index

Comment: The smart way is to declare an array. Why would you want anything else?

Comment: All these comments and the answer all seem to have a common theme.... There is probably a good reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

No. Just use an array, what is wrong with that?

```cpp
int r[15] = {0};
```

Comment: Empty initialiser is forbidden in C, though some compiler may allow it.